# Imagemagick Arc

Tags: imagemagick, automatic-ref-counting

Hi I am having trouble with what I am creating using Imagemagick.

Here's the scripts:

```
convert 
-size 300x300 xc:skyblue 
-background none 
-fill #AF280E 
-stroke none 
-draw "circle 150,150 75,250" 
-fill white 
-stroke none 
-draw "circle 150,150 75,240" 
-fill #D3DADF 
-stroke none 
-draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,1 ,41 150"' 
-fill #AF280E 
-stroke none 
-draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,0 ,41 150"' 
-fill white 
-stroke none 
-draw "rectangle 290,140 10,170" 
-fill white 
-stroke #AF280E 
-strokewidth 5 
-draw "line 10,137 290,137" 
-strokewidth 40 
-fill white 
-stroke #D3DADF 
-strokewidth 5 
-draw "line 10,170 290,170" 
-strokewidth 40 
-fill white 
-stroke none 
-annotate 100,50 
-draw "circle 150,150 75,150" 
-background none
-font Bookman-Light 
-pointsize 12 
-fill navy label"arc text here"  
-distort Arc 340 
logo_2_b6.gif
```

I wanted to place the arc text over those circles but it keeps on blinking and seems even the shapes created where arc too.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your command line with ImageMagick commands.

Lets write this a bit more readable and add writing of temp files after each step. This is Unix syntax for your code:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue +write t1.png \
-background none -fill #AF280E -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,250" +write t2.png \
-fill white -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,240" +write t3.png \
-fill #D3DADF -stroke none -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,1 ,41 150"' +write t4.png \
-fill #AF280E -stroke none -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,0 ,41 150"' +write t5.png \
-fill white -stroke none -draw "rectangle 290,140 10,170" +write t6.png \
-fill white -stroke #AF280E -strokewidth 5 -draw "line 10,137 290,137" +write t7.png \
-strokewidth 40 -fill white -stroke #D3DADF -strokewidth 5 -draw "line 10,170 290,170" +write t8.png \
-strokewidth 40 -fill white -stroke none -annotate 100,50 +write t9.png \
-draw "circle 150,150 75,150" +write t10.png \
-background none -font Bookman-Light -pointsize 12 -fill navy label:"arc text here" +write t11.png \
-distort Arc 340 logo_2_b6.gif
```

Here I have fixed your code:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue +write t1.png \
-background none -fill "#AF280E" -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,250" +write t2.png \
-fill white -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,240" +write t3.png \
-fill "#D3DADF" -stroke none -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,1 ,41 150"' +write t4.png \
-fill "#AF280E" -stroke none -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,0 ,41 150"' +write t5.png \
-fill white -stroke none -draw "rectangle 290,140 10,170" +write t6.png \
-fill white -stroke "#AF280E" -strokewidth 5 -draw "line 10,137 290,137" +write t7.png \
-strokewidth 40 -fill white -stroke "#D3DADF" -strokewidth 5 -draw "line 10,170 290,170" +write t8.png \
-strokewidth 40 -fill white -stroke none -annotate +100+50 " " +write t9.png \
-draw "circle 150,150 75,150" +write t10.png \
-background none -font Arial -pointsize 12 -fill navy label:"arc text here" -compose over -composite +write t11.png \
-distort Arc 340 logo_2_b6.gif
```

First, your line that ends in +write t9.png makes no sense to me. The -annotate syntax is -annotate +X+Y "some text". You have the wrong syntax for the +X+Y (you have X,Y). Second you have no text. What are you trying to do? See my equivalent line ending in t9.png. I have corrected your syntax and added some empty text, since I do not know what you are trying to do here.

Second and what fails is your label.  It must be label:"some text". You left off the colon (:).

Third, that line causes you to have two versions of t11.png, namely, t11-0.png and t11-1.png. Label creates a new image. It does not write on the previous image. So you need to add -compose over -composite for it to show in a single t11.png

It also helps to look at each image created to see if it is producing the correct result for that step.
So what I get from my command is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will try to figure out my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

As **fmw42** mentioned, there are several problems with your command. Consider a few improvements...

A single setting for things like fill color, stroke color, and strokewidth will work on all following operations until you need to change them. You don't have to do it that way, but it can help keep your code less cluttered.

Make your label *and* do the arc distort it inside parentheses to avoid distorting the rest of the logo you created earlier in the command. It's also helpful to specify the outside and maybe inside radii in that "-distort arc" operation when you make the curved text.

Your output is a GIF, so you need to "-composite" the text onto the logo graphic before writing the output, otherwise IM will make an animated GIF and your text will be blinking.

Here is a command that works for me on IMv6.8.9 running in a bash shell. It might help get you going in a good direction...

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue +size -background none \
   -stroke none \
   -fill "#AF280E" -draw "circle 150,150 75,250" \
   -fill white -draw "circle 150,150 75,240" \
   -fill "#D3DADF" -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,1 ,41 150"' \
   -fill "#AF280E" -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,0 ,41 150"' \
   -fill white -draw "rectangle 290,140 10,170" \
   -strokewidth 5 \
   -fill white \
   -stroke "#AF280E" -draw "line 10,137 290,137" \
   -stroke "#D3DADF" -draw "line 10,170 290,170" \
   -strokewidth 40 \
   -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,150" \
   +strokewidth \
   \( -font Bookman-Light -pointsize 36 -fill navy -virtual-pixel none \
        label:"arc text here" -distort Arc "340 0 68" \) \
   +repage -gravity center -composite logo_2_b6.gif
```

[image]

EDITED TO ADD:

I added another "label:" and adjusted the radius to make a second piece of text and make it compatible with the first. It has to be rotated before the arc distort to make the lettering proper side up.

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue +size -background none \
   -stroke none \
   -fill "#AF280E" -draw "circle 150,150 75,250" \
   -fill white -draw "circle 150,150 75,240" \
   -fill "#D3DADF" -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,1 ,41 150"' \
   -fill "#AF280E" -draw 'path "M 260 150 A 1 1,0,0 ,0 ,41 150"' \
   -fill white -draw "rectangle 290,140 10,170" \
   -strokewidth 5 \
   -fill white \
   -stroke "#AF280E" -draw "line 10,137 290,137" \
   -stroke "#D3DADF" -draw "line 10,170 290,170" \
   -strokewidth 40 \
   -stroke none -draw "circle 150,150 75,150" \
   +strokewidth \
   -gravity center \
   \( -font Bookman-Light -pointsize 48 \
        -fill "#D3DADF" -virtual-pixel none \
        label:"\              upper arc             " \
        -distort Arc "360 0 115" \) \
   -gravity center \
   +repage -composite \
   \( -font Bookman-Light -pointsize 48 \
        -fill navy -virtual-pixel none \
        label:"\              lower arc             " \
        -rotate 180 -distort Arc "360 180 115" \) \
   +repage -composite logo_2_b8.gif
```

[image]

It can be extremely challenging to work with areas of curved text in ImageMagick. Notice I had to add spaces and do rotations to make sure both text labels matched each other in size and location of center. Different fonts, varying amounts of text, and even using the same font name on different machines can all affect the exact placement of text.

It might be helpful to study the "[Circular and Radial Distortion](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#circular_distorts)" operations for some help creating and aligning circular images.

Comment: Hi thank you for this this is what I am trying to do text should be arc in the maroon area, then another arc text on the gray area

Comment: See my addition to my first solution for another example command and comments.

Comment: Thank you it looks good, but why my result is different from yours, I am running a version 7 of bash shell [link](https://futurebeaches.com/FB/Images/logo_2_b8.jpg)

Comment: Your arc distortions must stay inside the parentheses, otherwise they'll affect the other parts of your image. That's what seems to be happening. Make sure all your parentheses are escaped with backslashes "\\(...\\)".

Comment: I have tried to put backslashes on each script but it still affects the circle and even the background. Then I tried to place the arc script comes first this is the result. (https://futurebeaches.com/FB/Images/logo_8_b8.gif)